# How to delete a selected shape in openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm currently seeing this example of openlayers ( http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/draw-features.html ) whichs draws lines, circles etc. on the map. I edited the code to be able to select a drawing. I was wondering how can I delete a selected drawing? Here is how i select the drawing:

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I found this usefull link and i figured out the answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126909/remove-selected-feature-openlayers-3

Comment: And how would you like to delete it? `Del` key?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the feature by removing it from the layer when it has been selected. Use a 'add' listener on the features selected in the interaction, and delete it from the source of the layer.
Use

```js
select = new ol.interaction.Select();
select.getFeatures().on('add', function(feature){
  //source is layer.getSource()
  source.removeFeature(feature.element);
  feature.target.remove(feature.element);
});
map.addInteraction(select);
```

JSFiddle link (select delete in the dropdown to select and delete a feature):
http://jsfiddle.net/anushamc/edms856o/